# passport-google does not properly log out

Tags: passport.js

I have the following in my app.js

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  console.log("Test "+req.isAuthenticated());
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Then I have the following in my index route...

```
console.log("IsAuth "+req.isAuthenticated());
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
  console.log("Logged In");
}
else{
  console.log("Logged Out");
}
```

But the console shows...

```
Test false
GET /logout 302 5ms - 90
IsAuth true
Logged In
GET / 304 91ms
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a side effect of using Oauth.Just how it works the lines are a little less clear.

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot of code that you posted looks fine, and is more or less also the same I have on my github project for express 4 on 
[github-gpassport](https://github.com/rageboge/gpassport)
 that is working correctly in my browsers (chrome and safari).

That's a port to express 4 of an old express 3 version and I had some issue at the beginning configuring the session correctly.